# How to change filename via Upload.aspx

Tags: file-upload, ie8

I've managed to upload a file using the code below

```
<a onclick="openDialog(); return false;" href="#">Open Attach File</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openDialog() {
            var options= {
                url: "<blahblahblah>/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={blahblahblah}&RootFolder=",
                title: "Attach File",
            };
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
        }
    </script>
```

My question is how do I change the filename retroactively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In library, take one extra column say as "test" and then check upload file. It will redirect to other page in which you got all properties in edit mode. You can change title from there.

Comment: Thank you Sam for replying. Am hoping you can expand a little more. I am 2weeks old into Sharepoint, and struggling. How do you redirect to another page? How do you get Upload.aspx to return you a result parameter? Appreciate

Comment: Do you know how to create column? If yes then just create new column and name as "test". If not then check this link. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-add-a-column-in-a-list-or-library-2b0361ae-1bd3-41a3-8329-269e5f81cfa2